# subprocess VS function VS Parallel programs in /etc/profile

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have made 3 python codes. I am using a Raspberry Pi

- Code 1 - Prints Barcode on a button press
- Code 2 - Sends Barcode to Server
- Code 3 - Runs in background to record data in case of network failure and resend data once internet comes on.

Note: All these codes are running in a `while(True)` loop

Now, I have to run all these 3 programs Parallel to each other. I have read about 3 options I have

**SubProcess** - Where I import the python codes into one code using subprocess() and run them

**Using /etc/profile** - Where i put in the following line in the end of `sudo nano /etc/profile`

```
sudo python3 (link to code1) & sudo python3 (link to code3)
```

This runs fine...although I have been caught in an infinite loop now and then and don't feel very comfortable with it.

**Defining functions** - Where I define two programs as functions in the biggest of the 3 codes and run them at very quick intervals.

Now all of these 3 do give me outputs with few errors here and there now and then. But I want to know...which is the BEST possible and most Efficient way to run multiple programs in parallel to each other

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the most universal. That's how this type of programs works -- they work in different processes, maybe even on different machines or containers and work with each other via a network/ipc API.

Option 2 is almost the same, but it doesn't make sense. [`/etc/profile` is invoked only for login shells because that is its specific purpose.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells) You need an option to start the program under a different user. If you plan to restart the programs, why not using the same mechanism for starting it for the first time?

Option 3. If you run the app in different functions in one process -- too much headache. And you have problems with time -- which function is running at which point. You could use multithreading, but it might be too complicated for your use case. Though if the second app is just submitting network requests, it's quite a viable solution. code 2 and 3 would be the same app. Run it in a second thread -- it will collect the data to a local sqlite database, and send the messages which are no marked as submitted yet (the same idea applies for option 1).

Comment: what if I run these 3 programs using function definitions OR using threading...AND my 4th program, which simply records time and restarts the rpi as soon as it hits 3am, I run this program using /etc/profile. AS, I need to run this entire operation on RPi bootup.

Comment: Use supervisord to handle all the processes. It gives you all you need. You can [start it on boot](http://serverfault.com/q/96499/98756). But don't use `/etc/profile` -- it's for something different. And your app will not restart if you don't login -- for example after a restart because of a power failure.

Comment: i need my apps to restart after the rpi boots up. I'l have to do some fidgiting with autologin i suppose?

Comment: Have you looked at the link in my prev. comment?

Comment: i did. I am going to try it once I am back home with my rpi. I'l update you with the results.

Comment: I tried installing supervisor for python3. Using 'sudo pip3 install supervisor'.
it says "Please install using a supported version"

Comment: supervisord is for Python 2 only. Do `sudo pip install supervisor`. Or install it  using `apt`

Comment: but all my modules and all my code is for python3. i have installed all modules using 'pip3 install'
i will have to reinstall all modules for python 2.

Comment: supervisor is a program for managing any processes, not just python apps. So it's necessarily your app's dependency. It's just a helper app to manage your python app.